# all tincymce's switch when updating page after changing from html to text in custom metabox

Tags: custom-field, metabox, tinymce, wp-editor

I have a custom metabox which uses wp_editor and when i switch to text editor instead of visual the main content tinymce also changes to text view when i update. I was wondering am i doing something wrong or is that normal behavoir for wordpress when creating a custom metabox and wp_editor?

the code i use to set all of this up is:

```
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'page_tagline_meta_box');
function page_tagline_meta_box($post) {
    global $post;
    $post_id = $_GET['post'] ? $_GET['post'] : $_POST['post_ID'] ;
    $homepage_id = get_option('page_on_front');

    $screens = array( 'services', 'page');
    if($homepage_id != $post_id) {
        foreach ($screens as $screen) {
            add_meta_box('page_tagline_id', 'Tagline text & Telephone number', 'page_tagline_meta_box_cb', $screen, 'normal', 'high');
            add_meta_box('additional_content_id', 'Additional Content', 'additional_content_meta_box_cb', $screen, 'normal', 'high');
        }
    }
}
function additional_content_meta_box_cb($post) {
    global $post;
    wp_nonce_field('additional_content_box_nonce', 'additional_content_meta_box_nonce');

    $values = get_post_custom($post->ID);

    $additionalContent = isset($values['additionalContent']) ? $values['additionalContent'][0]: '';

    $settings = array(
        'textarea_rows' => 15,
        'wpautop' => true
    );

    wp_editor($additionalContent, 'additionalcontent', $settings);
}
```

If you would like to see the save function you are welcome to but i know it all saves and i can get the content out in my templates. its just when i switch views on the custom metabox it also switches the view of the main text area for the page when i hit update which i find quite odd.

Thanks in advance for your help

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is, as you guessed, default behavior. It's stored in the wp_usermeta table for each user in the wp_user-settings meta_key and does not differentiate between different editor instances.

On a side note, the tinymce version of wp_edior() does not cooperate very well with being inside a meta box. Especially if the metabox is moved, or hidden then shown, etc. I'd highly recommend either using the quicktags version only or not using a metabox (use any of a number of hooks in edit-form-advanced.php).

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. I did read that it isnt ideal to use after i wrote this question and did do some research to try and find some help on the edit-form-advanced but couldn't find anything to learn from.

Is there anything you'd suggest i could look at. Im still new to hooks and trying to get my head around them.